# Find documents in a collection that contain some letters in a variable in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use this pattern to find documents that contains 'a'

```
  const doc = await canton.find({libelle:/^a/})
```

but when I use it as variable like the next example it doesn't work :

```
 const doc = await canton.find({libelle:/^req.params.libelle/})
```

any solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator,

**For contains "a"** - [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1_cFRtY1tb5)

```
const doc = await canton.find({
  libelle: { $regex: req.params.libelle }
})
```

**For start with "a"** - [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ApuBckYeJam)

```
const doc = await canton.find({
  libelle: { $regex: "^"+req.params.libelle } // or `^${req.params.libelle}`
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const re = new RegExp(`^${req.params.libelle}`);

const doc = await canton.find({libelle: re});
```

Something like this? Haven't tested it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution by convert it to regular expression by this code

```
     req.params.name = new RegExp("^"+req.params.name);
```

ty